# Odd even not working in css

Tags: css

```css
.timeline-centered .timeline-entry .timeline-entry-inner .timeline-icon:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #fad839;
}
.timeline-centered .timeline-entry .timeline-entry-inner .timeline-icon:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #21a9e1;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline-centered" id="ulnotifications">
  <article class="timeline-entry">
    <div class="timeline-entry-inner">
      <div class="timeline-icon"></div>
      <div class="timeline-label">
        <h2><a href="#" id="anoti" notiid="162d3607-a71e-1803-228d-5434df80a346" style="text-decoration: none; color:#fff" class="ui-link">Gaurav Bansal  joined this life group.</a></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="timeline-entry">
    <div class="timeline-entry-inner">
      <div class="timeline-icon"></div>
      <div class="timeline-label">
        <h2><a href="#" id="anoti" notiid="6cef2b1b-b478-6a08-7488-5433dd7399b8" style="text-decoration: none; color:#fff" class="ui-link">Aravind M  joined this life group.</a></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="timeline-entry">
    <div class="timeline-entry-inner">
      <div class="timeline-icon"></div>
      <div class="timeline-label">
        <h2><a href="#" id="anoti" notiid="b23190cc-af8a-1c10-bf76-5433be250268" style="text-decoration: none; color:#fff" class="ui-link">Elca bs  joined this life group.</a></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="timeline-entry">
    <div class="timeline-entry-inner">
      <div class="timeline-icon"></div>
      <div class="timeline-label">
        <h2><a href="#" id="anoti" notiid="d8c28074-aedf-da68-624d-5433b19801ae" style="text-decoration: none; color:#fff" class="ui-link">Vin Katyal  joined this life group.</a></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="timeline-entry">
    <div class="timeline-entry-inner">
      <div class="timeline-icon"></div>
      <div class="timeline-label">
        <h2><a href="#" id="anoti" notiid="54f80046-cc56-1838-0483-543386f544c7" style="text-decoration: none; color:#fff" class="ui-link">Vin Katyal  joined this life group.</a></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="timeline-entry">
    <div class="timeline-entry-inner">
      <div class="timeline-icon"></div>
      <div class="timeline-label">
        <h2><a href="#" id="anoti" notiid="d387b5e0-12bf-05c8-d9f1-54338337e970" style="text-decoration: none; color:#fff" class="ui-link">Vin Katyal  joined this life group.</a></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="timeline-entry">
    <div class="timeline-entry-inner">
      <div class="timeline-icon"></div>
      <div class="timeline-label">
        <h2><a href="#" id="anoti" notiid="e36357e7-c6b4-49ec-d4cf-542cf4af3d81" style="text-decoration: none; color:#fff" class="ui-link">Catherine Rodrigues added you as their wife</a></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="timeline-entry">
    <div class="timeline-entry-inner">
      <div class="timeline-icon"></div>
      <div class="timeline-label">
        <h2><a href="#" id="anoti" notiid="ea9fd63b-863d-6fc1-c98e-542bbdacaff4" style="text-decoration: none; color:#fff" class="ui-link">gh</a></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="timeline-entry">
    <div class="timeline-entry-inner">
      <div class="timeline-icon"></div>
      <div class="timeline-label">
        <h2><a href="#" id="anoti" notiid="62e00001-cc6d-3e3b-397b-542b9733b5ed" style="text-decoration: none; color:#fff" class="ui-link">g</a></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="timeline-entry">
    <div class="timeline-entry-inner">
      <div class="timeline-icon"></div>
      <div class="timeline-label">
        <h2><a href="#" id="anoti" notiid="b78ba209-aede-34b9-317b-542b80a3ef44" style="text-decoration: none; color:#fff" class="ui-link">jasdjasd</a></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

It only shows me the yellow color for the odd field and not the even one.

Please help

Comment: Can you do a jsfiddle of this?  It'll be way easier to debug.

Comment: @WillBriggs here you go http://jsfiddle.net/fhaot02a/

Comment: What is the question? You should clearly identify what you expected and how the actual behavior differs. Things like “odd field” are far too vague. Specify exactly what elements you are referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are selecting even and odd `.timeline-icon` elements. But there is only one icon for each entry, so each icon's index is 1 and they will all be considered odd.

I suggest selecting icons within even and odd `.timeline-entry` elements instead, like so:

```css
.timeline-centered .timeline-entry:nth-of-type(odd) .timeline-entry-inner .timeline-icon {
    background-color: #fad839;
}
.timeline-centered .timeline-entry:nth-of-type(even) .timeline-entry-inner .timeline-icon {
    background-color: #21a9e1;
}
```

[**WORKING EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mz0jqd6h/)

### Edit:

Applied to your posted fiddle, it [looks like **THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/fhaot02a/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:

```
.timeline-centered .timeline-entry:nth-of-type(odd) .timeline-entry-inner {
    background-color: #fad839;
}

.timeline-centered .timeline-entry:nth-of-type(even) .timeline-entry-inner {
    background-color: #21a9e1;
}
```